# rxjava timer throws timeout exception after subscribe has successfully executed

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have following code:

```
repo.getObservable()
            .timeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSubscribe {
                _isInProgress.value = true
            }
            .doFinally {
                _isInProgress.value = false
            }
            .subscribe(
                    {
                        Timber.d("Success")
                    },
                    {

                        Timber.e(it)
                    })
            .trackDisposable()
```

The problem with it is that I'm successfully getting Success message after couple seconds, yet my preloader still waits for 1 minute and then my error part of subscribe gets executed. Is that expected behaviour? What can I do to stop timeout if success part of subscribe gets executed?

P. S. Observable returned from getObservable() is created like this: PublishSubject.create()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need one result, use `take(1)` before or after `timeout`:

```
repo.getObservable()
        .take(1) // <---------------------------------------------
        .timeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnSubscribe {
            _isInProgress.value = true
        }
        .doFinally {
            _isInProgress.value = false
        }
        .subscribe(
                {
                    Timber.d("Success")
                },
                {

                    Timber.e(it)
                })
        .trackDisposable()
```

Answer (score 2):

That must be because you are not calling `onComplete` on the PublishSubject and only `onNext` is called.
See this example:

```
PublishSubject<Integer> source = PublishSubject.create();

// It will get 1, 2, 3, 4 and onComplete
source.subscribe(getFirstObserver()); 

source.onNext(1);
source.onNext(2);
source.onNext(3);

// It will get 4 and onComplete for second observer also.
source.subscribe(getSecondObserver());

source.onNext(4);
source.onComplete();
```

Until `onComplete` is called the observers are waiting for more results.
You can either `unsubscribe/dispose` after the reception of the result you were waiting for or call `onComplete` on the Observable when all the results have been sent.

Comment: I never call onComplete as my subject should be reusable. How would I unsubscribe after I get result? How do I get access to disposable in subscribe method?

Comment: save the `repo.getObservable()` return in a variable and I suggest you just call a method in your success callback, this way in that method you can call your current code (`Timber.d("Success")`) and also the unsubscribe method of that previously saved var. Keep in mind you should also unsubscrive of that observable if it's still active and the activity or fragment is destroyed or the app is going to have memory leaks.

Comment: getObservable() returns PublishSubject. If I save that to variable how do I use it to unsubscribe? There is no unsubscribe method on PublishSubject.

Comment: `PublishSubject` is of type `Subject` which is of type `Observable`. And `Observable` has `unsubscribeOn(scheduler)` method. And the scheduler you are setting is `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`

Comment: Yes, there is unsubscribeOn method but all it does is specifies on which thread should unsubscribe operation be performed. It doesn't give me disposable object which I could use in "subscribe success" method to unsubscribe.

Comment: I've just checked and what I do is saving the result of the `subscribe()` call which should be of type `Subscription` and has the `unsubscribe()` method.

Comment: If I call subscribe() on PublishSubject I only get Disposable object which only has dispose method. What dependency do you use?

Comment: well, easy then, just call `clear` or `dispose`, the `unsubscribe` was renamed to `dispose` at some rxjava version. Sorry, I didn't think about it earlier on

Comment: Now things start to get ugly. Subscribe must be called before I get a Disposable object, and then inside subscribe success I need to use the same variable that stores disposable, but that variable did not exist before subscribe call so I have to use some ugly global variable for that and even add more ugly null/initialization checks. Please tell me I'm wrong on this...

Comment: the var should be stored on your activity/fragment wherever you subscrive and the success callback will have access to it. Just call this new method of the activity/fragment with the `Timber.d("Success")` instruction and the `dispose` call which you can set as the callback

Comment: The best thing is that you can check this way if this disposable is set and dispose it if the activity/fragment is finished preventing from memory leaks. If you don't dispose it I'm pretty sure the activity/fragment would not be released waiting for the completion of that observable